# Proving that this map is not retract of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

This question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve this particular problem.

> Edit 1 : Following the comments of Arctic char: I have attempted all three parts taking r(x)=x. for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

> A subspace Y of $\mathbb{R}$ is said to be retract of $\mathbb{R}$ if there exists a continuous map r:$\mathbb{R} \to Y$ such that r(y)=y for every $y\in Y$.

(A) Show that [0,1] is a retract of $\mathbb{R}$.

(B) Determine whether every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a retract of $\mathbb{R}$.

(C) Show that (0,1) is not a retract of $\mathbb{R}$.

> I want some hint for (C) and It is solution verification for (A), (B).

(A) I took r(y) = y for every $y\in Y$ and if y<0 r(y)=0 and if y>1 then r(y)=1.

(B) The most general closed set for $\mathbb{R}$ is $\bigcup_{i=1}^n [a_i ,b_i]$  and I can define r(y) = y:  $\mathbb{R} \to \bigcup_{i=1}^n [a_i ,b_i]$.  here also define all y<0 as r(y)=0 and y>1 as r(y)=1 and the function is continuous.

(C) For (C) , I thought again of using r(y) =y on (0,1) and   I am unable to say what should I define it for r>1 and r<0 so as to make it continuous. Now, I need to prove that there doesn't exists any continuous map $r: \mathbb{R} \to Y$. if I assume the existence of a continuous map $r
:\mathbb{R} \to (0,1)$ such that r(y)=y  for every $y\in (0,1)$. But I am unable to think of a contradiction.

Can you please help.

Comment: Your (A), (B) are both wrong....In both case you havent defined $r$.

Comment: It just seem that you have some misunderstanding of what a function $r : \mathbb R \to Y$ is.

Comment: @ Arctic chair I think r(x) =x where r is defined as r(x) =x is the function I mean.

Comment: So in (A) what is $r(2)$?

Comment: @James $r$ has to be defined on $\mathbb R$ with the range in $Y$.

Comment: @ Arctic Char r(2) =2

Comment: But $2$ is not in $Y = [0,1]$.

Comment: @ArcticChar You are right

Comment: Given your edit, I am not sure if you understand.... the map $r(x) = x$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ does not work: it is not a function $f : \mathbb R \to Y$ (unless $Y = \mathbb R$).

Comment: If you write $r: \mathbb{R} \to Y$, it means that $r(x) \in Y$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. However, in the case where $Y=[0,1]$, defining $r(x):=x$ makes no sense, since $r(2)=2 \notin [0,1]$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

For all the questions, $r: \mathbb R \to Y$ should be defined on $\mathbb R$ **and take values in $Y$**.

**Question A**

Take

$$r(x)= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x \lt 0\\
x & \text{ if } x \in [0,1]\\
1 & \text{ if } x \gt 0
\end{cases}$$

**Question B**

Your assumption that *The most general closed set for $\mathbb{R}$ is $\bigcup_{i=1}^n [a_i ,b_i]$* is wrong. For example $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} [2n, 2n+1]$ is closed but is not a finite union of closed bounded intervals.

The answer to the question is negative as the image under a retraction (a continuous map) of $\mathbb R$ which is connected has to be connected. However $Y=\{1, 2\}$ is closed but not connected.

**Question C - Hint**

Derive a contradiction from the fact that $r$ is continuous, $r(x)= x$ for $x \in (0,1)$ while $r(0) \gt 0$.

Comment: And, in fact, there are closed sets like the Cantor set which are not the union of countably many intervals - indeed, the only “intervals” in the Cantor set are single point intervals.